# how to add column name in table type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

how to add column name in table type

```
alter table type typemaster add emplpoyee varchar(48)
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql

Comment: alter table mytable add [name] varchar(48)

Comment: you ask to add column name in the title of your question, but in the content of your question you have a statement to add a column emplpoyee. So, what exact is your question ??

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table type add name varchar(48)
```

Answer (score 0):

type is a reserved keyword so you need to surround the table name in brackets.

```
--the technical answer
alter table [type] add emplpoyee varchar(48)
```

But the name is indeed a reserved keyword, and this is bad practice to be doing this.  It is better to rename the table to something different.

```
--rename the table to something different
exec sp_rename 'type', 'mytype'
```